# Shopping cart rule : discount if 2 different sku are in cart

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, discount

I'm looking to build the following Shopping Cart Rule and I have no idea how to do it.

I have multiple sku available, if you add 2 different sku in your cart, you get 10% off.  It can be any combination of sku, no matter the quantity, and the discount is only applied once.

Comment: resolve your problem?

Answer (score 5):

This can be done through the standard Magento promotion rules.

Go to Promotions->Shopping Cart Price Rules. Fill in the relevant information for your in the first tab.

In the conditions tab click on the green plus under the rule that says:

```
If ALL of these conditions are TRUE
```

Select Products Attribute Combination in the drop down menu. This will then add the line:

```
If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true:
```

Select the green plus again and choose SKU from the menu. Click on the ... and the enter the SKU of the first item.

Repeat this using the bottom green plus and enter your second SKU. You then should have a page that looks like:

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

    If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true:
        SKU  is  12345 

    If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ALL  of these conditions true:
        SKU  is  123456
```

Finally click on actions tab and enter 10 discount amount box.

Save the rule.

You will now get 10% off your whole order if both products are present in any quantity.

Comment: I get that I can do it with condition, but I have about 30 sku (at the moment) doing it for every possible combination will not be productive.

Comment: I can't create Rule for every possibilities, as they will become cumulative and I can't make this rule stop any other rules, since I have other promotion going at the same time

Comment: OK. Perhaps you could re-word the original question as what you are asking for now seems materially different to what was originally requested. Make it clear that any one of hundreds of products could be in the product list. Explain how you would want to indicate which products are included and that you need to have other offer rules processed without being affected by this rule.

Comment: ok thanks, i've modified the question, hopefully it will make more sense

Comment: discount amount high compare than what i gave.

Answer (score 2):

In the conditions tab click on the green plus under the rule that says:

> If ALL of these conditions are TRUE

Select Products SUB SELECTION in the drop down menu. Then make the condition as:

> If total quantity  is  2  for a subselection of items

Finally click on actions tab and enter 10 discount amount box.Save the rule.